# How run python with html or php?

Tags: php, python, html

2 file is in the root:
index.html or index.php , script.py
I want to run the python program by clicking on the button on the Html(or php) page.
is it possible?
if yes, please guide me.
if no, what solution you recommend?

Comment: You need a server in the mix somewhere.

Comment: If your server can run Python, then yes you can do this easily. What host, or what server software are you running?

Comment: I think http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php could be of use.

Comment: Do you have sample code for this? user6056648
i run program in ubuntu virtual server with python,php,apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a GET method on the form where the button is in like this

```
$activateScript = $_GET['activeScript'];
exec("python /path/to/file.py $activateScript");
```

Tell me if it works or not :D

Comment: maybe you also need to set the permissions to execute the python command. By default php disable this for the security.